# How to check for the existence of a variable or a member of a struct?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, struct, boolean

Let's say I have many boolean variables (I am attempting to make text based adventure game and I am going to need the path to diverge depending on the selected choices), is there a simple way to check if a given string is equal to a name of a initialized variable or a member of a initialized struct? (So that I can change the variable from false to true, for example?)

Comment: Nope. Once the program is compiled all those nice variable names are gone and replaced by memory offsets.

Comment: Maybe you want a `std::map<std::string, bool>` in the class?

Comment: or `std::set<std::string>`.

Comment: No, C++ doesn't work this way. If you need many of anything, you create a *collection* of these things, rather than a variable for each thing. If you need to find things by a string, use a collection that is indexable by string, such as std::map.

Comment: Sorry, C++ doesn't provide for run-time reflection. Luckily.

Comment: Hmm, I will look into using a map in that case. Thank you for comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example of using [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to fight a monster.

```
std::map<std::string, bool> flags;
```

defines and allocates a list of named flags that may or may not be true. This list can be used

```
if (flags["key"])
```

looks in `flags` to see if "key" exists. If it does, the mapped value (`true` or `false`) will be returned. If it does not exist, and this is a major difference if you are familiar with Java, "key" is created and set to the default value (`false` in this case).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void slaymonster(std::map<std::string, bool> & flags)
{
    //check if hero has sword of monster slaying
    if (flags["has sword of monster slaying"])
    { 
        flags["monster slain"] = true; // sets key "monster slain" to true so
                                       // hero can do stuff that requires
                                       // monster to have been slain
        std::cout << "Thou hast slain the monster!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Thou hast been slain by the monster!\nInsert coin to continue.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, bool> flags;

    std::cout << "Try to slay monster before finding sword\n";
    slaymonster(flags);

    std::cout << "\nHero finds sword of monster slaying\n";
    flags["has sword of monster slaying"] = true;
    std::cout << "Try to slay monster after finding sword\n";
    slaymonster(flags);

    std::cout << "\nHero is mugged and loses sword of monster slaying\n";
    flags["has sword of monster slaying"] = false;
    std::cout << "Try to slay monster after losing sword\n";
    slaymonster(flags);
}
```

Output:

```
Try to slay monster before finding sword
Thou hast been slain by the monster!
Insert coin to continue.

Hero finds sword of monster slaying
Try to slay monster after finding sword
Thou hast slain the monster!

Hero is mugged and loses sword of monster slaying
Try to slay monster after losing sword
Thou hast been slain by the monster!
Insert coin to continue.
```

Comment: This is awesome! Very well explained and a very relevant example too! Thank you!